# Makefile: make text file and append strings in it

Tags: makefile

I'm having difficulties with makefiles.

So in a recipe, I'm making a file (with a name and a .ujc extension) in a for loop and would like to have a text file at the end which contains all the created files. Purpose is to feed it to an application.

For example, in a semi high-level example,

```
List= [Class1,Class2,Class3]
foreach(Class C in List) {
    #do operations on C > outputs a ClassX.ujc file
    # add name of file to a text file named "list_of_files"
}
```

At the end I should have a text file, list_of_files.txt, which contains the following string:

```
Class1.ujc Class2.ujc Class3.ujc
```

As a reference, the code I have at the moment (and which does a bit of the stuff above  but does not work is) is:

```
pc: $(APP)
$(foreach C, $(shell echo $(CLASS) | tr ',' ' '), \
make -C BUILDENV CLASS=$(C) BUILD=just_filelist OUTPUT=filelist.txt SKIPSELF=yes && \
../classCvt/classCvt <./Applications/$(C).class> ./Applications/$(C).ujc && \
cat app_file_list.txt | xargs echo ./Applications/$(C).ujc >app_file_list.txt && \
) true
time -p ./$(APP) `cat app_file_list.txt` `cat filelist.txt`
```

The internal make does make a filelist which is fed to the app, but I'd also like to feed the app_file_list but its construction goes totally wrong.

Probably simple, but I'm not getting there.

Edit:

The code below does what I want:

```
pc: $(APP)
rm -f cat app_file_list.txt
$(foreach C, $(shell echo $(CLASS) | tr ',' ' '), \
make -C BUILDENV CLASS=$(C) BUILD=just_filelist OUTPUT=filelist.txt SKIPSELF=yes && \
../classCvt/classCvt <./Applications/$(C).class> ./Applications/$(C).ujc && \
cat app_file_list.txt | echo ./Applications/$(C).ujc >>app_file_list.txt && \
) true
time -p ./$(APP) `cat app_file_list.txt` `cat filelist.txt`
```

Notable mistake I made was the xargs.

Comment: You can't read from and output to a file in the same pipeline like that. The output redirection happens *first* and blows away any contents before the commands (`cat` in this case) gets to read the file. That said where does `app_file_list.txt` come from in the first place? **That** said why are you doing this all in a shell loop for a single make target? Why not make the actual output files make targets and let make actually do its job? What is your *actual* goal here?

Comment: I fail to describe it adequately it seems but don't know how to do it better.

On every 'make pc' I want to generate a new text file, app_file_list, that contains the C (the .ujc files) from the foreach loop.

Comment: I've managed to fix it using your advice (was thinking in a different direction), solution is in the edit.

Comment: Answering your own question is perfectly valid. If you have an answer you should write it up as one and explain what you changed and why. Then you can accept it. Editing a solution into the post is not a good model.

Comment: Done below. Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Also in the post) 
The solution turned out to be not-so-difficult. I needed to remove the xargs command and do the correct operation (i.e., >> instead of >) in the 'cat app_file_list.txt | etc...' line.
The code below does what I want:

```
pc: $(APP)
rm -f cat app_file_list.txt
$(foreach C, $(shell echo $(CLASS) | tr ',' ' '), \
make -C BUILDENV CLASS=$(C) BUILD=just_filelist OUTPUT=filelist.txt SKIPSELF=yes && \
../classCvt/classCvt <./Applications/$(C).class> ./Applications/$(C).ujc && \
cat app_file_list.txt | echo ./Applications/$(C).ujc >>app_file_list.txt && \
) true
time -p ./$(APP) `cat app_file_list.txt` `cat filelist.txt`
```

Notable mistake I made was the xargs which caused strings to repeat into the .txt file.

Comment: `echo` doesn't read from standard input so `cat ... | echo` doesn't do anything useful. You can remove it. `echo ... >> app_file_list.txt` will append to the file just fine.